# Using VBA to Import XML into MS Access with xslt transform file

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, xslt

I'm trying to import a bunch of .xml files into Access tables. I've created a .xslt file that works fine when I manually run the import in Access. But when I try using VBA code (which I pulled from another post here) to transform the .xml file, the resulting temp.xml file is completely empty. What am I missing?

```vb
Public Sub TransformAndImportMultipleXMLs()
   Dim strFile As String, strPath As String

   Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
   Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
   Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

   strPath = "y:\"
   strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xml")

   xslDoc.async = False
   xslDoc.validateOnParse = False
   xslDoc.resolveExternals = False

   xslDoc.Load "C:\JSTAdb\LinkIncidentID.xslt"

   While strFile <> ""
      ' REINITIALIZE DOM OBJECTS
      Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
      Set newDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

      ' LOAD XML SOURCE
      xmlDoc.Load strPath & strFile

      ' TRANSFORM SOURCE
      xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
      newDoc.Save "C:\JSTAdb\temp.xml"

      ' APPEND TO TABLES
       Application.ImportXML "C:\JSTAdb\temp.xml", acAppendData
       strFile = Dir()
   Wend

   'RELEASE DOM OBJECTS
   Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post sample XML and XSLT. Also, how do you *manually run the import in Access*?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The .xml files were from an InfoPath form and contained a number of large photo attachments. I wasn't waiting long enough for the result to be Transformed. I just needed a bit of patience. It's working OK now.